# Basic Auth not working if FilesMatch is in place

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am having a strange issue where if the `<FilesMatch>` is set the basic auth does NOT work. If I comment out the `<FilesMatch>`, the basic authentication works.

I replaced the ips for now with `1.1.1.1`

```
#htaccess authentication
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Preview Site"
AuthUserFile /var/www/mywebsite.com/.htpasswd
Require valid-user


<FilesMatch ".*">
    Require ip 1.1.1.1/23
    Require ip 1.1.1.1/22
</FilesMatch>

#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You have error, or the Basic Auth are not prompt ? And why make a restriction in .* files ?

Comment: @Inazo Found it. It was something to do with the Require ip. Used the old method from Apache 2.2